# An intuitive explaination..

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a problem, to whose answer I want an intuitive explanation.

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_5$ be independent continuous random variables having a common distribution function $F$ and density $f$.

Let $I= P\{X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4<X_5\}$.

The answer I think is $\frac{1}{120}$ i.e. $\frac{1}{5!}$

Can someone give me an intuitive explanation as to why such is the answer? What is the relation between $X_{(5)}$ and $5!$?

Comment: Since the distributions are continuous, the probability of equality is $0$. And now y symmetry all orders are equally likely.  Probably that was the idea that led you to $1/5!$.

Comment: The events $X_{i_1}<X_{i_2}<\cdots<X_{i_5}$ are mutually exclusive and equally likely. They are not quite exhaustive, but the complement of the union of these events has probability zero. So summing the probabilities of these events over all 120 permutations must give 1, and since each is equally likely, the answer is $1/120$. (This is just another way of saying what André said.)